# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, linker, linker-errors

My friend recently asked me to debug his app and then sent me the project. However after downloading the project I got the following errors and warnings:

[image: Errors and warnings]
He claims he does not have any errors in his project.

I tried googling this problem but had no success.

Thank you!

Comment: In your project build phases check the section titled "Link Binaries with Library". Those libraries should be referenced there. Remove them. If that causes lots of errors then your friend has them somewhere and needs to get them to you in order to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project build phases check the section titled "Link Binary with Libraries". Those libraries should be referenced there. Remove them.

If that causes lots of errors then your friend has them somewhere and needs to get them to you in order to compile

Answer (score 1):

It seems the project has reference to AviarySDK on a fixed location on a computer.

Try deleting AviaraSDK from frameworks or whatever and add it again and make sure you Copy that sdk into project folder.